# Why array's append method cannot be used in viewController?

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I am beginner of swift. I tried to use array's append method in my code but it doesn't work. How should I implement the array correctly?

The error messages:
Swift Compiler Error Group
ViewController.swift:16:5: Expected declaration
ViewController.swift:11:7: In declaration of 'ViewController'

I tried to use array's append method in my code but it doesn't work.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController { //Error msg: In declaration of 'ViewController'

@IBOutlet weak var dice: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var dice2: UIImageView!
var dices : [String] = []
dices.append("Hi") //Error: Expected declaration

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func rollPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dice.image = UIImage(named: "dice3")
}

}
```

I expect I can add `"hi"` into the array `dices`.

Answer (score 3):

You should call the `append` inside a function after the vc is fully initated

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { //Error msg: In declaration of 'ViewController'

@IBOutlet weak var dice: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var dice2: UIImageView!
var dices : [String] = [] 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    dices.append("Hi") // e.x here
}

@IBAction func rollPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dice.image = UIImage(named: "dice3")  
}

}
```

**Or** replace

```
var dices : [String] = []
```

with

```
var dices = ["Hi"]
```

Answer (score 1):

SH_Khan is right. I'll explain why though.

When defining a `class`, the first level of indentation is only for its methods and properties, aka `func`, `var`, and `let`. (You can also define other classes/structs/enums in there too)

Calling those functions or system functions like `Array.append()` or `print("dog sweat")` must happen inside of another function. The reason why is that your application's live logic is literally just functions all the way down. No function gets called unless it's inside of another function first. (The only exceptions are Swift's quick and dirty initializations like setting a default value to a `var` outside of an `init() { }` or another function.)

A dog doesn't wake up from its nap unless you make some noise. It won't do it on its own. (crappy metaphor, but yeah)

I hope that made any sense.